# Notice: Undefined index: tid in taxonomy_field_formatter_prepare_view() (line 1669 of

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm getting this error on my website. I have tried cleaning up the content type of all fields but it still shows up.

Any ideas what could be causing it, and how to debug?

Thanks a lot,

Chiko

Comment: Getting a similar issue, how did you fix it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your content have an taxonomy_term reference field which have invaild data, maybe it break.

You can install devel module and use error display with debug_backtrace and you will see where it comming.

Answer (score -1):

1 Open Content Type,
2 manage field tab, clieck save.
3 manage display tab, click teaser , default,  and save